# Apache Camel SFTP is asking for Username and Password in the console

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-camel

Though I've added a `username` and `password` still camel route is asking for a username and password in the console.

Dependency -

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.20.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-ftp</artifactId>
    <version>3.20.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Camel Route -

```
URI uri = new URIBuilder().setScheme("sftp").setHost("HOST.com").setPort(22)
           .setUser("demo_user", "demo_password").build();

from(uri.toString()).to("file://src/main/resources);
```

After running this in the console it's showing -

```
19:01:41:158 [main] WARN o.a.c.c.file.remote.SftpOperations - JSCH
Kerberos username:
```

I want to run the application and the `username` & `password` should automatically take but sadly it's not taking, any solution, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I got the solution.
I passed a parameter - `preferredAuthentications` as `password` and after that, it's working

```
URI uri = new URIBuilder().setScheme("sftp").setHost("HOST.com").setPort(22)
       .setUser("demo_user", "demo_password").addParameter("preferredAuthentications", "password").build();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
from("sftp://HOST.com:22?username=demo_user&password=demo_password")
   .to("file://src/main/resources");
```

Comment: tried that also, but still asks for the same username and password.